# Why would the number of flags go up?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, flagging

I have noticed over the last few days that the number of flags remaining has been increasing. When I flag a question, it appears that I start at 13 now.

So, what would cause my number of flags to go up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess I should have searched all of the meta sites...

It turns out that there is a formula used to increase the flag quantity based on activity.

[Recent changes to flagging and limits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185888/on-the-recent-changes-to-flagging-and-limits)

> You start with 10 flags per day.
>
> Based on your reputation and flagging history, you can end up with as many as 100 per day.
>
> Currently, that means you get an extra flag per day for every 2000 reputation points or 10 net helpful flags (helpful-unhelpful).

Comment: Can you lose flags?

Comment: It looks like you can. If you start having a lower ratio of helpful/not helpful, it is possible.